# VBA - Hide certain column in every worksheet of workbook when checkbox is not selected

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to hide every "A" column in my workbook when a certain checkbox in my user form is not selected.

I have 6 worksheets in my one workbook.

I have 6 checkboxes.

When a checkbox is not selected, I'd like to hide the column that it's associated with.

Ex: When the "Advice" checkbox is not checked, I'd like to hide the "A" column in EVERY worksheet in my workbook.

Thank you!

I tried this:

```
shtFinancial.Range("D").EntireColumn.Hidden = Not cbAdvice.Value
```

And this:

```
If cbAdvice.Value = True Then
shtFinancial.Range("D").EntireColumn.Hidden
```

Comment: Just add a loop, going over all Worksheet objects (say `oWS`) in `Thisworkbook.Worksheets`. So `oWS.Columns("A").Hidden = Not cbAdvice.Value`

Comment: you did not say what happened when you ran the code that you posted ....  you are referencing `D` in the code ... record a macro of doing the column A hide

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes in VBA are really funky. Here is one method:

```
Sub cbAdvice_Click()
    Dim CheckBox As Shape, ws As Worksheet
    Set CheckBox = Sheet1.Shapes("cbAdvice")
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If CheckBox.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
            ws.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            ws.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I created two active x control boxes "CheckboxColA" and "CheckboxColB" and gave them the following code for a change of state:

Sheet1("Worksheet Controls")

```
Private Sub CheckboxColA_Change()
    Call changeColAVisiblity(CheckboxColA.Value, "A")
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxColB_Change()
    Call changeColAVisiblity(CheckBoxColB.Value, "B")
End Sub
```

Then created the following code in "module1"

```
Sub changeColAVisiblity( _
    cbState As Boolean, _
    changeColumn As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'If statement Assumes sheet with contols should not change
        If ws.Name <> "CheckBox Controls" Then
            ws.Columns(changeColumn).Hidden = cbState
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```